# "ranges is null" JavaScript error when setting reputation date range

Tags: profile-page, javascript, reputation-graph, bug

When I go to the Reputation tab of my profile, manually edit the date range in the text boxes and click SET the graph and reputation list remains unchanged.

In FF 3.5 Firebug shows the following JavaScript error (note that I've allowed all the listed domains in NoScript):

```
ranges is null
$("#start-date").val(convert...ToDate(ranges.xaxis.from.toFixed(1)));
```

Chrome 3 gives a different wording of the same error.

IE 8 shows a different JavaScript error:

```
Line: 250
Error: 'xaxis' is null or not an object
```

Comment: This is still happening, I realised if the range is less than 4 days, the error will be thrown. Say today is 2010/02/11, to view the past 1 day, I have to enter 2010/02/10 to 2010/02/14!

Comment: Is anyone looking at this at all????

Comment: I'm still seeing this in IE8 for any date range set manually.

Comment: Rep graph no longer works this way